# Green function and differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I'm trying find the Green's function for a special operator.
I have the homogeneous equation

```
x (x - 1) y''[x] - 2 I Zm y'[x] - L(L + 1) y[x]==0
```

for $x>1$ everywhere. $Zm$ is real and $L$ is a positive integer.
Mathematica can solve this equation easily in terms of Hypergeometric functions.

Now I would like to find the Greens function of this problem.

First attempt: I tried using the predefined function `GreenFunction` as

```
 GreenFunction[{x (x - 1) y''[x] - 2 I Zm y'[x] - l (l + 1) y[x],y[1] == const1, y[\[Infinity]] == 0}, y[x], {x, 1, x1}, s,Assumptions ->x > 1 && l > 0 && const1 > 0 && && x1 > 1 && s > 1]
```

This doesn't evaluate, I've also tried to modify the boundary conditions as

```
GreenFunction[{x (x - 1) y''[x] - 2 I Zm y'[x] - l (l + 1) y[x], y[1] == const1, y[x2] == const2}, y[x], {x, 1, x1}, s, Assumptions -> x > 1 && l > 0 && const1 > 0 && const2 > 0 && x1 > 1 && s > 1 && x2 > x1]
```

This did't help.

Second attempt is that I tried just simply to put the right hand side of the equation as the `DiracDelta`

```
x (x - 1) y''[x] - 2 I Zm y'[x] - l (l + 1) y[x] == DiracDelta[x - x1]
DSolve[%, y[x], x, Assumptions -> x1 > 1] // Simplify
```

Alas we have a result.

My question is why doesn't the `GreenFunction` function give the desired output?
Another would be how do I do I impose the boundary values on the result given. If I for example require that `y[Infinity] ==0` in the second attempt, I don't get a solution.

Comment: @Nittaaa Your last attempt `DSolve` gives a result including `Inactive[Integrate]` and `DiracDelta[]`, Dont't know why Mathematica won't evaluate, perhaps you might solve it manually?

Comment: Hello, the integration can be activated using `Activate` function, with some `Assumtpions` and `Fullsimplify` this does reduce, but I'm wasn't sure how to apply different boundary conditions (just the conditions that I mentioned are really important) to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know why Mathematica `GreenFunction` doesn't evaluate.

Perhaps your last attempt might be elaborated a little bit further:

```
ode = x (x - 1) y''[x] - 2 I Zm y'[x] - l (l + 1) y[x] == DiracDelta[x - x1]
Y = Values@DSolve[{ode, y[1] == 1}, y , x ][[1, 1]] // Simplify
```

This solution, with one boundary condition `Y[1]==1`, includes   `Inactive[Integrate]` and `DiracDelta[]`, which have to be activated.

```
green = Function[{x, x1}, 
Simplify[Activate[Y[x] ], {Element[{x, x1}, Reals], x1 > 1 }] //Evaluate]
```

Solution fullfills the bc

```
green[1, x1] /. HeavisideTheta[0] -> 1/2
(* 1 *)
```

Solution `green` depends on parameter `C[1]` which follows from condition `Limit[Y[x],x->Infinity]==0`

```
solc = Solve[0 == Asymptotic[green[x, x1], x -> Infinity],C[1]][[1]];
```

**addendum**

alternative solution idea (two bc)

```
ode = x (x - 1) y''[x] - 2 I Zm y'[x] - l (l + 1) y[x] ==DiracDelta[x - x1]; 
Y = Values@DSolve[{ode, y[1] == 1, y[inf] == 0},y, x][[1, 1]] //Simplify; 
green = Function[{x, x1},Simplify[Activate[Y[x]], {Element[{x, x1,inf}, Reals], x1 > 1,       inf > 1}] // valuate];
Asymptotic[green[x, x1], inf -> Infinity];
```

Unfortunately the last codeline doesn't evaluate, because further knowledge of paramter `Zm,l` is needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that `C[1]` should be a constant. Perhaps that's where my surprise confusion on this began. Could you please confirm that `C[1]` is really just a parameter dependant on $x$? That is $C[1] = C[1](x)$ mathematically?
If so I will accept you answer and perhaps begin a thread on why doesn't the Greenfunction evaluate.

Comment: @Nitaaa You are right, C[1] must be a constant. Last step in my answer seems to be wrong.

Comment: Perhaps If we instead use the condition `solc = Solve[0 == Asymptotic[green[x, x1], x -> Infinity],C[1]][[1]];` ? We do get an answer, although quite unreadable, but clearly independent of $x$.

Comment: @Nitaa Yes that's the correct condition. Hopefully independent of x (?and x1?).I modified my answer

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I've rechecked the code and the solution is dependent on $x$ (and also x1). Which doesn't seem resonable to me.

Comment: It looks like Mathematica isn't able to evaluate `Asymptotic` without knowing `Zm,l`. Try alternatively `ode = x (x - 1) y''[x] - 2 I Zm y'[x] - l (l + 1) y[x] == 
  DiracDelta[x - x1];
Y = Values@DSolve[{ode, y[1] == 1, y[inf] == 0}, y, x][[1, 1]] // 
  Simplify; green = Function[{x, x1}, 
  Simplify[Activate[Y[x]], {Element[{x, x1, inf}, Reals], x1 > 1, 
     inf > 1}] // Evaluate];Asymptotic[green[x, x1], inf -> Infinity];
`

Comment: Thank you, I've tried few specific values of Zm and L that could be relevant to my problem. I will give an update.